# TCP server not receiving data from RFID reader

Tags: c#, tcp

I am trying to connect to my RFID reader via an ethernet connection. I have connected the RFID reader to my router and then connected my Desktop to the same router via an ethernet connection.

[Connection diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpfYv.png)

Every time a RFID tag is detected by the RFID reader the tag's ID will then be sent to my PC. I have writer some very basic TCP server/client code to receive this data. The PC is the server and the RFID reader is the client.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         public Form1()
         {
           InitializeComponent();
         }

         SimpleTcpServer server;

         private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            server = new SimpleTcpServer();
            server.Delimiter = 0x13;
            server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;
         }

         private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
         {
            txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                txtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
                e.ReplyLine(string.Format("RFID: {0}", e.MessageString));
            });
         }

         private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.5.10");
            server.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32("6910"));
         }
   }
}
```

The way the RFID is setup to send the tag data to the PC via ethernet is by using a Macro. This is shown below. So the most important part is the notifyAddress which is in the form of hostname:port.

```
AutoModeReset
persisttime= 1
AntennaSequence = 0 
AutoAction = Acquire
AutoStartTrigger = 0,0
AutoStopTimer = 0
AutoTrueOutput = 1
AutoTruePause = 1000
TagListCustomFormat = %k 
NotifyAddress = 192.168.5.10:6910
NotifyFormat = Custom
NotifyHeader = Off
NotifyTrigger = True
NotifyMode = On
AutoMode = On
```

The IP address of the PC/server is 192.168.5.10 with port number 6910. I have created an exception in my firewall for this port. However, I am still not receiving any data from the RFID reader. Can someone assist?

Comment: Are you using an Alien reader?

Comment: @MarioV yes I am

Comment: I can see that you are using Alien protocol on the reader side, I would have to double check if you are missing  a parameter, so maybe that is why the reader is not sending data, but I just wonder, why don't you use Alien SDK C#. Net to develop the server client, it is very easy to implement, it has good documentation, and in that way you don't reinvent the wheel. Do you have Alien SDK?

Comment: @MarioV I do but I do not know how to use it exactly. Is there any examples or info that can help me to set this up, in a step by step way?

Comment: @MarioV I see Alien provides a really nice doc for the ruby and java, but I cannot find any thing like this for .Net SDK. So I do not know how to setup a network listener and ho to retreive the tag data using the .Net SDK

Comment: there is very good documentation, unfortunately the zip file for the lates C#.NET SDK does not come with it, but try to download the version 2.3.0, this version comes with the documentation and examples, the documentation and examples are good for the lates version, use it to communicate with the reader, it will do your  coding much easier.

Comment: @MarioV thank you, I am connected to the reader using the "mReader.InitOnNetwork(ip, port);result = mReader.Connect();" but when I use the if (mReader.Login("alien","password")) it keeps on returning false. I used the Java gateway to confirm the username and password and it is "alien" and "password". Can you help me as to why the reader is failing to connect?

Comment: @MarioV nevermind I was using the F800 with an old .dll. Updated it and it works now. Thanks again for making me aware of the SDK. It is really straightforward!